# Больше не следить за изменениями в файле

Tags: git, github

Я сделал коммит определенного файла. Теперь мне не надо, чтобы GIT следил за изменениями в этом файле. Как мне это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 8):

Если я правильно вас понял, то вам нужно выполнить следующее

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged your_file
```

После этого гит не будет реагировать на какие-либо изменения в этом файле, чтобы отменить это поведение, выполните следующее

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged your_file
```

Comment: Спасибо. То что нужно! И последние изменения в файле остались закоммиченными. И новые изменения не отслеживаются!

Answer (score 5):

В svne есть changelistы и ignore-on-commit, однако этот подход обычно считается неправильным.

В git'e под source control'ом должны располагаться файлы, изменения в которых **должны попадать в репозиторий.** Если файл больше не нужен в репозитории, то делайте `git rm your-file-name`.

---

Если вы временно внесли изменения в файл (например для тестирования) но не хотите их коммитить, то правильный подход - используйте `git stash` для этих файлов на время коммита.

Comment: Плюсанул, поскольку ответ правильный. Я бы еще добавил внесение имени файла `.gitignore`

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сделать это, используйте опцию `--cached`

```
$ git rm --cached readme.txt
```

[Другая полезная штука, которую вы можете захотеть сделать — это удалить файл из индекса, оставив его при этом в рабочем каталоге.](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9)